# Python Multiprocessing queue limitations in different conditions

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def WORK(x,q,it):
        
        for i in range(it):
            t = x + '---'+str(i)
               
            q.put(t)
      
def cons(q,cp):
    while not q.empty():
         cp.append(q.get())
    return q.put(cp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cp = []
    it = 600 #iteratons
    start = time.perf_counter()
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = WORK, args = ('n',q,it))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=WORK, args=('x',q,it))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cons, args=(q,cp,))
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()


    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    print(q.get())
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start)
```

I encountered a problem running this code in Pycharm and Colab, if i run this in colab it works fine only with 1000 iterations and less in **WORK()** process, if more - it freezes.
In Pycharm it works fine only with 500 iterations or less
What is a problem??? Any limitations?

So i find not very good solution is to remove join or put it after dict call from queue, it help to get mor limits, with this code it started to work with 1000 iterations in pycharm but 10000 iteration is deadlock again

```
p1.join()
p2.join()
print(q.get())
p3.join()
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)
```

Further change helped me to increase iterations limit to 10000 by adding queuq maxsize:

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize = 1000)
```

So what is limitations and laws with this queues???
How to manage endless queue, from websockets for example, they sends data continiously

Comment: Read the documentation on `multiprocessing.Queue`! You must not try to  `join` a process that is writing to a queue *before* you have read all the records from that queue.

Comment: Like That? Hot helped((

    print(q.get())
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your code. First, according to the documentation on `multiprocessing.Queue`, method `empty` is *not* reliable. So in function `cons` the statement `while not q.empty():` is problematic. But even if method `Queue.empty` were reliable, you have here a *race condition*. You have started processes `WORK` and `cons` in parallel where the former is writing elements to a queue and the latter is reading until it finds the queue is empty. But if `cons` runs before `WORK` gets to write its first element, it will find the queue immediately empty and that is not your expected result. And as I mentioned in my comment above, you must not try to join a process that is writing to a queue before you have retrieved all of the records that process has written.

Another problem you have is you are passing to `cons` an empty list `cp` to which you keep on appending. But `cons` is a function belonging to a process running in a different address space and consequently the `cp` list it is appending to is *not* the same `cp` list as in the main process. Just be aware of this.

Finally, `cons` is writing its result to the same queue that it is reading from and consequently the main process is reading this result from that same queue. So we have another race condition: Once the main process has been modified not to read from this queue until after it has joined all the processes, the main process and `cons` are now both reading from the same queue in parallel. We now need a separate input and output queue so that there is no conflict. That solves this race condition.

To solve the the first race condition, the `WORK` process should write a special *sentinel* record that serves as an *end of records* indicator. It could be the value `None` if `None` is not a valid *normal* record or it could be *any* special object that cannot be mistaken for an actual record. Since we have two processes writing records to the same input queue for `cons` to read, we will end up with two sentinel records, which `cons` will have to be looking for to know that there are truly no more records left.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

SENTINEL = 'SENTINEL' # or None

def WORK(x, q, it):
        for i in range(it):
            t = x + '---' + str(i)
            q.put(t)
        q.put(SENTINEL) # show end of records

def cons(q_in, q_out, cp):
    # We now are looking for two end of record indicators:
    for record in iter(q_in.get, SENTINEL):
        cp.append(record)
    for record in iter(q_in.get, SENTINEL):
        cp.append(record)
    q_out.put(cp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    it = 600 #iteratons
    start = time.perf_counter()
    q_in = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q_out = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=WORK, args = ('n', q_in, it))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=WORK, args=('x', q_in, it))
    cp = []
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cons, args=(q_in, q_out, cp))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    cp = q_out.get()
    print(len(cp))

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start)
```

Prints:

```
1200
0.1717168
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution helped in this case, but i suppose it will not work in endless request process, i want to use multiprocessing for placing websockets request in separate process, this requests are very continious, task is practically unendable, so sentinel will not be usable because of endless process of exchange sockets data between processes,  so i  started to look in another modules, maybie it will be shared memory, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: You can always post a new question describing the new situation.